# Amazon Cloud Drive 404 <UnknownOperationException/>

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I am trying to get an access_token using the code I get once the permission is granted by the resource owner. My request is like:

URI:
https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token

BODY:
client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=%090xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&scope=clouddrive%3Awrite

HEADERS:
host    api.amazon.com:443
user-agent      MySockets
content-type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length  271
connection      close

I get the error:
404

Please can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that my socket library was sending "GET" http method. Once I set it to "POST" it worked!